# Adjust Last Operation Panel No longer appearing

Tags: interface

After using an animation my A.L.O panel box no longer appears at all. Creating a cylinder etc no longer brings up the option in the bottom left, I can use the adjust last operation function but Ideally need to bring the original operator box back up

I've also checked in preferences > system > Global undo and this is checked.

Downloaded the 3.6 alpha and it's working in there, until I load my save file.[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that you're not doing an action just after the one you want to correct? Also, you can still try F9 if you can't see the box

Comment: Nope, opened blender. timeline is showing at the bottom. No operations box when creating a new object even when closing the timeline down. F9 works to open the box but yet another button to press during workflow.

Comment: Ok that's weird

Comment: Yeah, I've reinstalled Blender twice. It's not there in any New>General options at all which makes me think it's something to do with preferences that have been changed

Comment: Nope check op, I've already looked into it. I've removed the files in appdata and done fresh installs but still remains the same. Checked the userpref.blend and startup.blend also.

It's saving the preferences somewhere else despite deleting the above files.

Comment: Solved

Needed to click the modelling tab at the top.

Comment: That also resets the setting in the view menu.

Comment: Well.. not exactly resets, but it's saved in the Modelling workspace as enabled, if you disabled it in that workspace, it would be saved as disabled and the panel would not show in Modelling workspace as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable or disable it in the View menu, in the header of 3D Viewport:

[image]

This setting is saved with the file with other UI settings.

Comment: Exactly, it is saved with a file and can be saved with the startup file. So if he probably saved the startup file with this option disabled this would explain why the function is missing even when creating a new file with _New_ > _General_.