# Blender Add Mesh menu is missing

Tags: mesh, interface

I know this is a simple question, but I cann't find the right words to describe the missing menu that pops up when you Add Mesh. What is it called? How do I get it back?

### Background

In a recent file, somehow I broke the system and when I add a mesh the window that pops up to give configuration options is missing.

What is this pop up window called?

Where do I go to add this back?

For example, I need this menu to change a circle into a hexagon. In the menu there are the number of vertices that I can change from the default of 32 down to 6 or 8.

[image]

Comment: It's called the Operator Box, or Last Operation box, and it will disappear as soon as you'll do a new action, like moving your object. If it doesn't appear just after creating your object there's a problem. You can still try to press F9

Comment: Is it not showing at all directly after you added a mesh? Or is it just collapsed? If so you can click on the little arrow to expand it.

Comment: @moonboots, the f9 did not do anything (perhaps because I am using a laptop without an external keyboard). But, thank you for the name of the box.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, correct, the box is not showing at all. Not collapsed.

Comment: @NascentSpace, your link was most helpful. The comments about " Edit > Adjust Last Operation " is my only option. And, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Update: This link and question has the best answer. Apparently, I unchecked this box and I didn't know what it was impacting. Now I know!
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293058/adjust-last-operation-panel-no-longer-appearing